# How to calculate a straight with a position vector (x,y) and a direction vector (x,y)

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, analytic-geometry

I want calculate the reflection from a straight **R** on the surface from the straight **BC**:

[image]

The triangle with the position vectors **A,B,C** are given. As well the position vector **P** and the direction vector **R**.

*what I can calculate:*

Now I can calculate the intersection point **D(x,y)** and the reflection vector (as a direction vector **R'**) and I know the **x** coordinate from the point **P'(x,?)** because the x value from the point P and P' are equals.

*what I cannot calculate:*

I need from the point **P'** the **y** coordinate. Because I need  position vectors for drawing the reflected line with python matplotlib.

How can I get the y coordinate from the point **P'** with the given parameters?

The reflected vector will go from **D(x,y)** to **P'(x,y)**

[matplotlib reflection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Bt1B.png)

Thanks  you!

Comment: How do you know that $x' = x$?  ...And what is $A$ for? It looks like you only need the line $BC$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have already solved the problem of reflection, so we can ignore everything except the point $\mathbf D$ and vector $\mathbf R',$ which you have computed, and the desired result $\mathbf P' = (x_P, y_{P'}),$
where $x_P$ is the $x$-coordinate of $P$ and is already given.

Take the coordinates $\mathbf D = (x_D,y_D)$ and $\mathbf R' = (r'_x, r'_y).$
The line in the direction $\mathbf R'$ from $\mathbf D$ then can be described by the equations
\begin{align}
x &= x_D + tr'_x,\\
y &= y_D + tr'_y,\\
\end{align}
where $t$ is a variable real number.

You can then find the value of $t$ that will given you the point $\mathbf P'$
by solving this equation:
$$ x_P = x_D + tr'_x. $$
Everything here is known except $t,$ so this is a simple linear equation to solve:
$$ t = \frac{x_P - x_D}{r'_x}.$$

Take this value and plug it into the formula for $y$:
$$ y_{P'} = y_D + tr'_y. $$

---

For some ways of setting up this problem, you could get a negative value of $t,$
for example if $\mathbf P$ was much further to the left and the vector $\mathbf R$ pointed downward to the right instead of to the left to reach $\mathbf D.$
In that case there would not be a valid solution, and a good diagram would confirm that there cannot be one.
But in the figure as you have drawn it, $t$ will be positive.

Comment: Hello David K Thanks you for your great explaination and your investet time. I implemented your recommended solution and it works total fine. @Ross Millikan Thanks you also!

Answer (score 0):

Work in polar coordinates with $D$ as the origin.  You can compute the angle that BC lies at.  If you add or subtract (depending on which end of $BC$ you choose) $\frac \pi 2$ you get the angle of the normal, which leaves $D$ in an upward right direction perpendicular to $BC$.  Call a point on it $N$.  Then use angle of incidence equals angle of reflection.  You have $\angle PDN=\angle NDP'$